# chocolatey: meteor v0.0.2 is the latest version available based on your source(s)

Tags: meteor, chocolatey

I follow the instructions to install meteor 1.6 on Windows(10) as stated on Meteor.com (`choco install meteor`) and it's installed a `meteor v0.0.2` ?

When I try to run any `meteor` command I get: `bash: meteor: command not found`

and when I try `choco upgrade meteor` I get:

```
$ choco upgrade meteor
Chocolatey v0.10.8
Upgrading the following packages:
meteor
By upgrading you accept licenses for the packages.
meteor v0.0.2 is the latest version available based on your source(s).

Chocolatey upgraded 0/1 packages.
 See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).
```

I tried `choco uninstall meteor` and then reinstall `choco instlal meteor` but same issue. Searching around online a little I found this page:

- https://chocolatey.org/packages/meteor

I do have meteor installed and running on version `1.6.0.1` on Window 10's Ubuntu `bash` which was installed via `curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh`

Comment: I am not sure about the Ubuntu bash part. You say you have installed it as the manual described, is the Ubuntu bash install a second install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following on from above post https://stackoverflow.com/a/47967277/642729 by Gary Ewan Park. The below comment on https://chocolatey.org/packages/meteor clarifies the Chocolately/Meteor versioning

> The current version of Meteor is 1.6; 
>   is this the version in the 0.0.2 Chocolatey package?
>
> [Garrie Powers • 2 months ago]
>
> The version number of the Chocolatey package is the version of the installer. 
>   Meteor is unique in the way it works in that all versions 
>   are capable of springboarding to other versions. 
>   Therefore, in the same way as the Unix installer installs the latest version, 
>   the Chocolatey installer will always install the latest version. 
>   So at this exact moment, the answer to your question is "yes"!
>
> [Jesse Rosenberger Garrie Powers • 2 months ago]

Answer (score 1):

The best advice would be to reach out to the maintainers of that package of chocolatey.org. This can be done by clicking on the "Contact Maintainers" link of this page:

https://chocolatey.org/packages/meteor

It would seem that the creators of the application, also own the Chocolatey package, so hopefully they will get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

From the [official installer github](https://github.com/meteor/meteor-chocolatey-installer):

> The version of this Meteor installer is **not to be confused with Meteor** itself. Meteor, once installed, will always "springboard" to (download, install and run) the correct version of Meteor necessary for the application being executed.
>
> ...
>
> When necessary, specific versions of Meteor can be installed using
> Chocoloatey's --params argument which will download that specific
> version from Meteor's installation server. For example, to install
> Meteor 1.5.4.4:
>
> C:> choco install meteor --params="'/RELEASE:1.6.0.1'"
>
> *Note: Prior to
> Meteor 1.6, 64-bit versions were not available. Therefore, in order to
> install versions prior to Meteor 1.6, you'll also need to pass
> Chocolatey's --x86 option when running choco install on 64-bit Windows
> platforms. For example:*
>
> C:> choco install meteor --x86 --params="'/RELEASE:1.5.4.4'"